# Load encrypted database from assets on android?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, android-sqlite, android-assets

I created an encrypted sqlite database with [SQLCipher *export*()](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).

I'm worried about security and reverse engineering of the apk, so the decrypt password is not in the app, but it is entered from the user on app start.

The problem is: **How can I read the encrypted database from assets folder?**

I've found libraries like [*SQLiteAssetHelper*](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) or [*ExternalSQLIteimporter*](https://github.com/javahelps/externalsqliteimporter) but they can't import encrypted databases.

Any idea?

Comment: Creating a fork of `SQLiteAssetHelper` that worked with SQLCipher for Android should take very little time.

Comment: I'm new to android, I don't know how to do that

Comment: This sounds like a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728 What is the difference to your problem? Or maybe others you find by searching for "[sqlite] assets".

Comment: @Yunnosch IT WORKS! Thank you so much, I just modified the code to work with sqlcrypt. This is the solution.